# Saving file to network location

Tags: windows, shared-directory

I have an application that has to save an uploaded file to 2 different servers for load balancing purpose. The first server (`serv01`) is the same server as the application that I'm building, so no problem. But when the code execute the upload process to the second server (`serv02`) using the following path;

```
\\serv02\path\path\
```

I get this exception "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.".

I suppose I have to add permission to asp.net user on the `serv01` to this network location, but how? If I tried to add permission, it always asks users from `serv02`. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running in a workgroup or a domain?

If a workgroup then setup the same account that your using for your AppPool account on both servers (matching username & password) so that workgroup networking will work.

If it's a domain it should just be a case of configuring your AppPool to use a domain user account that has permissions to write to the share on each server.

Comment: it's using Workgroup, and the AppPool account is Network Service.

Comment: @Arief I don't believe that you can grant rights to a remote machine account (e.g. NetworkService) when running in a workgroup. The easiest solution is to set up a user account (on both servers) and grant it access to the share(s) that it needs to access and use that to run the AppPool for this particular application. Alternatively you could setup some impersonation in the app for it to use when accessing networked resources.